# MySQL month over month totals compared to previous month

Tags: mysql

I'd like to sum the `amount` column for a given month, as well as the total for the previous month. Right now the first month's total works, but every month thereafter is too high by at least 2 order of magnitude.

```
SELECT month, year, total, previous_month, previous_year, previous_total FROM (
  SELECT MONTH(p1.start_date) AS month,
    YEAR(p1.start_date) AS year,
    SUM(p1.amount) AS total,
    SUM(p2.amount) AS previous_total,
    MONTH(DATE_SUB(p1.start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS previous_month,
    YEAR(DATE_SUB(p1.start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS previous_year
  FROM trackings p1 
  LEFT JOIN trackings p2 ON EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_SUB(p1.start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM p2.start_date)
  GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM p1.start_date)
) AS p3;
```

Related question: I'm doing the same `DATE_SUB` 3 times. Is there a way to clean up the date related parts to be more efficient?

Sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3013a/1

Comment: Please elaborate with some sample input outputs. I'm not following.

Comment: I agree with JackDev. Otherwise, it is just guessing.

Comment: @JackDev Apologies. Created a SQL Fiddle to show what I meant. The first month adds up correctly, but starting with the second row, the output is not correct (for the total and previous_total)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think the problem is you are getting rows counted multiple times on the join. Ie, you have a sum of all the amounts for a month, but each row from that month is being joined with all rows for the previous month.

Solution using a couple of subselect:-

```
SELECT ThisMonth.MONTH, ThisMonth.YEAR, ThisMonth.TOTAL, PrevMonth.MONTH AS PREVIOUS_MONTH, PrevMonth.YEAR AS PREVIOUS_YEAR, PrevMonth.TOTAL AS PREVIOUS_TOTAL
FROM
(
    SELECT MONTH(start_date) AS `month`,
            YEAR(start_date) AS `year`,
            EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM start_date) AS YearMonth,
            SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM trackings
    GROUP BY `month`, `year`, YearMonth
) ThisMonth
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT MONTH(start_date) AS `month`,
            YEAR(start_date) AS `year`,
            EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS YearMonth,
            SUM(amount) AS total
    FROM trackings
    GROUP BY `month`, `year`, YearMonth
) PrevMonth
ON ThisMonth.YearMonth = PrevMonth.YearMonth
```